# Running a couple of errors in a form with a button and textbox

Tags: c#

Here is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FJBch09ex10
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int num = r.Next(0, 100);
        int counter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;

            if (int.Parse(txt1.Text) > num)
            {
                lbl1.Text = "the number is too high";
                Form1.BackColor = HotTrack;


            }
            else {
                lbl1.Text = "the number is too low";
                Form1.BackColor = MenuHighlight;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Currently the r in r.Next is running an error.  The Form1.BackColor attempts are both running errors as well.  Any idea why these are running errors?  The r says "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field..."  Form1 says "an object reference is required for a non-static field..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int num; // you cannot use r there
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        num = r.Next(0, 100); // you can use r there
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

        if (int.Parse(txt1.Text) > num)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "the number is too high";
            BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack; // Form1 is the class


        }
        else {
            lbl1.Text = "the number is too low";
            BackColor = SystemColors.MenuHighlight; // Form1 is the class
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't assume that fields are being initialized in ordered they are declared. So you should move `num` initialization into constructor, or marks `r` as static.

   ```
   Random r = new Random();
   int num;
   int counter = 0;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       num = r.Next();
   }
   ```
2. `BackColor` is not static property of `Form1` class. It's an instance property, so you have to use `this` keyword or just set the property without any identifier:

   ```
   this.BackColor = MenuHighlight;
   ```

   or

   ```
   BackColor = MenuHighlight;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
Form1.BackColor = ...;
```

to

```
this.BackColor = ...;
```

as you wish to reference the current objects property, not a static property of the object.

And you need to set the value of num in the form constructor.

Something like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int num ;
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        num = r.Next(0, 100);

    }
    ....
```

Comment: I changed them but they both say that what I'm assigning to them does not exist in the current context.